# How to use a picture as an activation for if/else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, so what im trying to do is make a rock paper scissors type game, using jQuery.

How i need it to work is as follows.

Select a picture (clicking on it) which triggers the .click function(i assume that is what i would use) and then have the computer create a random number between 1 and 5. Those 5 numbers would then correspond each to a different picture. (i.e. 1- rock, 2 paper, 3 scissors, 4 lizard, 5 spock). I think would have a if/else statement setup to make it so it would be something like:
If computer chooses 1
 If you chose rock, tie
 else if you choose paper, you lose
 else if you choose scissor, you win
 else if you choose spock, you win
 else if you choose lizard, you lose
else if computer choose 2
etc. etc. etc.

Problem is i never learned how to do a input off a picture before, secondly, how to do rng so i can have the computer to play against.

So needless to say my code is incredibly bare bones since i dont  have a starting place to jump off of

Html just shows pics and header atm. JSfiddle for what its worth - http://jsfiddle.net/nndq3nnz/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<h1>Lizard, paper, scissors, spock, rock</h1>

<div id="images">
<img src="Images/lizard.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt=""/>
<img src="Images/paper.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt=""/>
<img src="Images/scissors.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt=""/>
<img src="Images/spock.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt=""/>
<img src="Images/rock.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt=""/>

<div id="comp">
</div>
<div id="win">
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="unit2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the Javascript:

```
$(function(){

    $('#play').click(function(){


    });//closes play function

});// closes function
```

im literally stuck at the start since i dont know how to initiate the rng or the image click. If i was using a button and radio buttons beneath the pictures to select them, this would be np, but i cant.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: you can probably [sic] create a random number with javascript, i'd google it. you can also name each of your pictures. recovering the name of an element with javascript is trivial. all of this can pretty much be run on the **client side**, without jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JQuery's `.click()` method on images, no problem there.

However you might as well wrap your images inside buttons so you can add values to them, and then use a single click controller retrieving the value of the button pressed.

This is how you'd do that particular thing:

```
<button class="game-button" value="1"><img src="Images/lizard.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt=""/></button>
<button class="game-button" value="2"><img src="Images/paper.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt=""/></button>
<button class="game-button" value="3"><img src="Images/scissors.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt=""/></button>
<button class="game-button" value="4"><img src="Images/spock.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt=""/></button>
<button class="game-button" value="5"><img src="Images/rock.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt=""/></button>
```

And some of the JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.game-button', function(event) {
    var value = event.target.val();

    // Then pick the computer's choice and run the game.
})
```

**EDIT:**
If you can't use buttons, then you could still add some `data-*` attribute to your images to carry the value, and put the click listener on the images.

This would be the way to do it:

```
<img class="game-image" src="Images/lizard.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" data-value="1"/>
<img class="game-image" src="Images/paper.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" data-value="2"/>
<img class="game-image" src="Images/scissors.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" data-value="3"/>
<img class="game-image" src="Images/spock.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" data-value="4"/>
<img class="game-image" src="Images/rock.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" data-value="5"/>
```

And some of the JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.game-image', function(event) {
    var value = event.target.data('value');

    // Then pick the computer's choice and run the game.
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. I don't know the rules for a spock or a lizard, but this is for a simple rock, paper, scissors.

```
    <script>
    var myChoice;
    var compChoice;
    function rock() {
    myChoice = 1;
    }
    function paper() {
    myChoice = 2;
    }
    function scissors() {
    myChoice = 3;
    }

    function runGame() {

    compChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3)) + 1;


    if (compChoice == myChoice) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML='tie';
    }

    if ((compChoice == 1) && (myChoice == 2)) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML='you win';
    }

    if ((compChoice == 1) && (myChoice == 3)) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML='you lose';
    }

    if ((compChoice == 2) && (myChoice == 3)) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML='you win';
    }

    if ((compChoice == 2) && (myChoice == 1)) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML='you lose';
    }

    if ((compChoice == 3) && (myChoice == 1)) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML='you win';
    }

    if ((compChoice == 3) && (myChoice == 2)) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML='you lose';
    }
    if (compChoice == 1) {
    document.getElementById("compChoice").src='http://newsdesk.si.edu/sites/default/files/imagecache/snapshot_image/PlymouthRockPiece.jpg';
    }

    if (compChoice == 2) {
    document.getElementById("compChoice").src='http://www.weissraum.at/wp-content/uploads/10_x_a4_wildflower_seeded_paper.jpeg';
    }

    if (compChoice == 3) {
    document.getElementById("compChoice").src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Skalm_2.JPG';
    }

    }
    </script>

    <h1>Lizard, paper, scissors, spock, rock</h1>

    <div id="images">
    <button onClick="rock();runGame();"><img src="http://newsdesk.si.edu/sites/default/files/imagecache/snapshot_image/PlymouthRockPiece.jpg" width="150" height="150" /></button>

    <button onClick="paper();runGame();"><img src="http://www.weissraum.at/wp-content/uploads/10_x_a4_wildflower_seeded_paper.jpeg" width="150" height="150" /></button>

    <button onClick="scissors();runGame();"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Skalm_2.JPG" width="150" height="150" /></button>
    </br>
    Computer Choice:
    </br>
    <img src="http://www.rankopedia.com/CandidatePix/85583.gif" id="compChoice" width="150" height="150"/>
    <div id="result">result</div>
    </div>
```